# Test AsycAction in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, async-await, moq

I have this code below, about a class responsible for handle exceptions and log them.

```
using ProReserve.Reserve.Domain.Licenciados;
using ProReserve.Reserve.Domain.Sistema.Logging;
using ProReserve.Reserve.Domain.Usuarios;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace ProReserve.Reserve.API.Filters
{
    public class DefaultControllerActionInvoker : ApiControllerActionInvoker
    {
        private Func<HttpRequestMessage, ILoggingService> _getLoggingService;

        public DefaultControllerActionInvoker(Func<HttpRequestMessage, ILoggingService> getLoggingService)
        {
            _getLoggingService = getLoggingService;
        }

        public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> InvokeActionAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> actionTask = base.InvokeActionAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken); // (*)

            if (actionTask.Exception != null &&
                actionTask.Exception.GetBaseException() != null &&
                actionContext.Request.Properties["Licenciado"] as Licenciado != null)
            {
                var exception = actionTask.Exception.GetBaseException();

                Operacao operacao = this.getHttpStatusCode(actionTask.Result); 

                await SaveLogAsync(exception, actionContext.Request, operacao);

                return await Task.Run(() => new HttpResponseMessage(actionTask.Result.StatusCode)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(exception.Message),
                    ReasonPhrase = "Error"
                });
            }
            return await actionTask;
        }

        private async Task SaveLogAsync(Exception exception, HttpRequestMessage request, Operacao operacao)
        {
            var guidLog = string.Format("{0}{1}", DateTime.Now.Ticks, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            var requestInfo = string.Format("{0} {1}", request.Method, request.RequestUri);

            var httpContext = request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextBase;
            var remoteAddr = httpContext.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            var serverName = httpContext.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
            var logonUser = httpContext.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
            var usuario = request.Properties["Usuario"] as Usuario;
            var message = string.Format("{0} {1}", exception.Message.ToString(), exception.InnerException != null ? exception.InnerException.ToString() : string.Empty);

            var logEntry = new Log(guidLog, operacao)
            {
                IDUsuario = usuario.ID,
                IPCliente = remoteAddr,
                IPServidor = serverName,
                MaquinaCliente = logonUser,
                Mensagem = string.Format(@"RequestInfo: {0} - Error: {1}", requestInfo, message),
            };

            using (var loggingService = _getLoggingService.Invoke(request))
            {
                loggingService.Licenciado = (Licenciado)request.Properties["Licenciado"];
                await Task.Run(() => loggingService.Inserir(logEntry));
            }
        }

        private Operacao getHttpStatusCode(HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            Operacao operacao = Operacao.Response;

            if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                switch (response.StatusCode)
                {
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest: //400
                        operacao = Operacao.BadGateway;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized: //401
                        operacao = Operacao.Unauthorized;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.PaymentRequired: //402
                        operacao = Operacao.PaymentRequired;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden: //403
                        operacao = Operacao.Forbidden;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound: //404
                        operacao = Operacao.NotFound;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed: //405
                        operacao = Operacao.MethodNotAllowed;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable: //406
                        operacao = Operacao.NotAcceptable;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ProxyAuthenticationRequired: //407
                        operacao = Operacao.ProxyAuthenticationRequired;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout: //408
                        operacao = Operacao.RequestTimeout;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict: //409
                        operacao = Operacao.Conflict;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Gone: //410
                        operacao = Operacao.Gone;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.LengthRequired: //411
                        operacao = Operacao.LengthRequired;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed: //412
                        operacao = Operacao.PreconditionFailed;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestEntityTooLarge: //413
                        operacao = Operacao.RequestEntityTooLarge;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestUriTooLong: //414
                        operacao = Operacao.RequestUriTooLong;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType: //415
                        operacao = Operacao.UnsupportedMediaType;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable: //416
                        operacao = Operacao.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed: //417
                        operacao = Operacao.ExpectationFailed;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError: //500
                        operacao = Operacao.InternalServerError;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented: //501
                        operacao = Operacao.NotImplemented;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadGateway: //502
                        operacao = Operacao.BadGateway;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable: //503
                        operacao = Operacao.ServiceUnavailable;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout: //504
                        operacao = Operacao.GatewayTimeout;
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.HttpVersionNotSupported: //505
                        operacao = Operacao.HttpVersionNotSupported;
                        break;
                    default:
                        operacao = Operacao.Response; //51
                        break;
                }
            }

            return operacao;
        }
    }
}
```

In the line (*) - `Task<HttpResponseMessage> actionTask = base.InvokeActionAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);)` - I have a command that intercepts an action async invoke. The variable `actionTask` returns with some properties. I need two of those properties filled, not null. They are:

- Result -> get the StatusCode returned
- Exception -> get the exception returned

I need both of those properties loaded, but I can't do a unit test where both of them are not null. In some test, Result comes not null, and other test, Exception comes not null, but never both of them.

Below is my unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ActionAsync_Com_Exception()
{
    // Arrange
    Log log = null;

    _loggingService.SetupSet(l => l.Licenciado = _licenciado);
    _loggingService.Setup(a => a.Inserir(It.IsAny<Log>()))
        .Callback<Log>((l) =>
        {
            log = l;
        });

    //Task<object> task1 = Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() => new Exception()); //(3)

    Task<object> task1 = Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        object myClass = new object();
        return myClass;
    });

    //_actionDescriptor.Setup(a => a.ExecuteAsync(It.IsAny<HttpControllerContext>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, object>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    //    .Throws(new Exception("exception"));   //(1)

    _actionDescriptor.Setup(a => a.ExecuteAsync(It.IsAny<HttpControllerContext>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, object>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns(task1); //(2)

    DefaultControllerActionInvoker actionInvoker = new DefaultControllerActionInvoker(r => _loggingService.Object);

    // Act
    HttpResponseMessage response = actionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync(_baseActionContext, CancellationToken.None).Result;

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, response.StatusCode);
    Assert.AreEqual("Error", response.ReasonPhrase);

    Assert.AreEqual("127.0.0.1", log.IPCliente);
    Assert.AreEqual("0.0.0.0", log.IPServidor);
    Assert.AreEqual("USER\\MACHINE", log.MaquinaCliente);
    Assert.AreEqual("RequestInfo: POST http://localhost/teste - Error: exception ", log.Mensagem);

    _loggingService.VerifySet(l => l.Licenciado = _licenciado);
    _loggingService.Verify(a => a.Inserir(It.IsAny<Log>()));
    _loggingService.Verify(a => a.Dispose());
}
```

In my test I have tried:

(1) In this case, it returns an exception, but Result property comes null.

(2) In this case, it returns a result, but Exception property comes null. In this case, I need also to mock some way, to return some error statuscode (40x or 50x). But I don´t know what to do.

(3) I have already tried creating a task which fires an exception, but gets into the case (2) above

So, I can't make my unit test works as well.

What do I need to do in my unit test code to get those two properties loaded?

Comment: Asynchronous tests are supported, just mark them as `async Task` instead of `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm following what's going on in your code, but the bottom line is that you have asynchronous completion going on, for which your test assertions are not waiting. It means that the assertions are executing while or perhaps before the asynchronous code executes, so they don't test the results.

The standard test framework doesn't adequately support async/await, so if you're calling a method returning something of Task, you have to wait on the task - essentially make your test code synchronous... given what you've done, I think one extra line may do the trick:

```
// Act
HttpResponseMessage response = actionInvoker.InvokeActionAsync(_baseActionContext, CancellationToken.None).Result;

// After you have obtained the returned Task object,
// and done whatever will initiate the asynchronous activity, wait for it to complete...
task1.Wait();  // <-- Try this

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, response.StatusCode);
```